# I have this code, how can I get only all the p under each h3 and put them to 3 lists

Tags: html

I have this code, how can I get only all the p under each h3 and put them to 3 lists, using Html Dom?

```
<h3>text</h3>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<h3>text</h3>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<h3>text</h3>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
<p>text</p>
```

What I mean is all the p below first h3 (above second h3) put into one list, the p below second h3 (above third h3) put into one list, the p below third h3 put into one list

Comment: html dom using what ? 
Pure JavaScript / jQuery ? or what exactly

Comment: What do you mean by "HTML DOM" ? and what do you mean by "lists"

Comment: I mean, using only something like document.getElementById...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You mean this?

```js
const texts = [...document.querySelectorAll("p")].reduce((acc, p) => {
  let tag = p.previousElementSibling;
  let currentHeader = tag.tagName === "H3" ? tag.textContent : Object.keys(acc).pop();
  acc[currentHeader] = acc[currentHeader]  || [];
  acc[currentHeader].push(p.textContent);
  return acc;
}, {})

document.body.innerHTML += Object.keys(texts).map(header => `${header}:<ul>${texts[header].map(text=> `<li>${text}</li>`).join("")}</ul>`).join("")
```

```html
<h3>Header 1</h3>
<p>text 1</p>
<p>text 2</p>
<p>text 3</p>
<h3>Header 2</h3>
<p>text 4</p>
<p>text 5</p>
<p>text 6</p>
<h3>Header 3</h3>
<p>text 7</p>
<p>text 8</p>
<p>text 9</p>
```

Comment: Using this method, I can only get first p of each h3 and put them to list. What I mean is all the p below first h3 (above second h3) put into one list, the p below second h3 (above third h3) put into one list, the p below third h3 put into one list

Comment: Thank you a lot for your answer ^^ It solved my problem ^^